# unreachable statement, menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.theme_switch);

Tags: javascript, java, android

1. First Section

package com.gmsofficial.GmSOfficial;

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton;
 import android.widget.Switch;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
 import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

2. Second Section

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

```
 public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {


 DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
 ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
 NavigationView navigationView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    if (loadState() == true){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
    }

    setUpToolbar();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
```

3.THird Section

```
    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_Website:

                    intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, Websitewebview.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_Mobiles:

                    intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, Mobileswebview.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
```

4. Forth Section

   ```
               case R.id.nav_TechNews:

                   intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, TechNewswebview.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;

               case R.id.nav_Gadgets:

                   intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, Gadgetswebview.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;

               case R.id.nav_CustomROM:

                   intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, CustomRomwebview.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;

                   menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.theme_switch);
                   final Switch themeswitch = (Switch) menuItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.action_switch);
                   if (loadState() == true){
                       themeswitch.setChecked(true);
           }
   ```
5. Unreachable error section

   ```
                       themeswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                           if (isChecked) {
                               AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                               saveState(true);
                               recreate();
                           } else {
                               AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                               saveState(false);
                           }
                       }
                   });
                   break;

               case R.id.nav_AboutUs:

                   intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, AboutUS.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;
   ```
6. sixth section
   //Paste your privacy policy link

   //      case  R.id.nav_Policy:{
   //
   //                        Intent browserIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(""));
   //                        startActivity(browserIntent);
   //
   //                    }
   //       break;
   case  R.id.nav_share:{

   ```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody =  "http://play.google.com/store/apps/detail?id=" + getPackageName();
        String shareSub = "Try now";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));

             }
               break;
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

   }
7. seventh section

   ```
   public void setUpToolbar() {
   drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
   Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
   drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
   actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
   actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
   ```

   }

   ```
   private void saveState(Boolean state){
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GmS Official", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("NightMode", state);
   editor.apply();
   ```

   }

   ```
    private Boolean loadState(){
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GmS Official", MODE_PRIVATE);
   Boolean state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("NightMode", false);
   return state;
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: Please Slove My Error

Comment: we have no idea how that code is to each other. Is it in one file? in one method? ... ?
We also don't know where exactly you get your error

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> break;
> menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.theme_switch);
> ```

I'm guessing you don't know what `break` does? These two lines are right next to each other and your compiler/editor is pointing you right at it. break will jump out of the `switch` statement entirely, there is no way for that `menuItem...` line to ever run, which is why the compiler is telling you: "This cannot be correct; I won't help you dig this grave any further.".

Comment: Why Please Help me

Comment: @Adi your question is equivalent to: "Please teach me java". That's a _tad_ too broad for a stackoverflow question, but there are plenty of tutorials out there!